# Some products disappeared from magento backend and frontend

Tags: magento, backend, product

Some of the products in Magento have suddenly disappeared from backend **and** frontend. When I try to re-create these products I get this error:

> The value of attribute "SKU" must be unique

So the products must still exist somewhere in the DB.

I already tried the following without luck:

- Truncate all catalog_product_flat tables
- ReIndex all indexes
- Refresh all Caches
- Checked the "status" attribute of the product in Mysql (it was set to 1)

Any ideas how I can get these products back in the frontend/backend?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the following tables:

- catalog_product_entity
- catalog_product_entity_datetime
- catalog_product_entity_decimal
- catalog_product_entity_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_group_price
- catalog_product_entity_int
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
- catalog_product_entity_text
- catalog_product_entity_tier_price
- catalog_product_entity_varchar

You can find the sku in the catalog_product_entity table.